# Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.[node.js]

Tags: node.js

Привет . Знатокам node.js

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host :'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'secret',
  port:3000
});
connection.connect();

//connection.query("SET SESSION wait_timeout = 604800"); 

connection.query('CREATE TABLE t1(id int)', function(error, rows, fields) {
    if (error){
    throw error;
    }else{
        console.log(rows);
    }
});



connection.query('select * from t1', function(error, rows, fields) {
    if (error){
    throw error;
    }else{
        console.log(rows);
    }
});



function keepalive() {
  connection.query('select 1', [], function(err, result) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    // Successul keepalive
  });
}
setInterval(keepalive, 1000*60*5);
```

Получаю ошибку Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. 
Использование функции keepalive() взято с совета на .stackoverflow.com 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942505/node-js-setinterval-connection-lost-the-server-closed-the-connection

**console.log(rows); не сработало ? Почему**

Может что-то прописать в конфигах?
Можно ли достучатся к mysql через консоль как в apache?
Альтернативы phpmyadmin v nodejs нету?

Comment: а зачем этот keepAlive?

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы городить костыли с keep alive, просто используйте пул соединений MySQL. модуль `mysql` позволяет делать это из коробки.